# How to re-define addition for custom classes?

Tags: r

I've seen some packages that defines new classes and binary operators like `+` or `-` still work. There must be a way to define how `+` operates according to the class of the two arguments, in a way like defining

```
plot.myclass = function(x) something
```

changes what `plot()` does if the argument is of class `myclass`.

How can I change what a built-in binary operator does? Do they work exactly like S3 methods?

As an example, let's say I want to have an addition operator for `character` objects, so that

```
"abc" + "def"
```

returns `"abcdef"`, how to specify that I want `+` to return `paste(arg1,arg2)` when the arguments are character objects.

Comment: You can use infix function sth like, sorry not tested but should work, ` ``%+%`` <- function(x, y)paste0(x,y)`, the left hand side statement should be wrapped in back ticks, its a back tick , not sure it rendered properly. You can use it like 'a' %+% 'b'

Comment: @PKumar if this works, I think it would break regular addition, as `1+1` would return `"11"`(character). I need it to change only for a certain type of arguments.

Comment: Are you talking about function or operator overloading

Comment: @李哲源 It's because `+` uses S4 not S3 dispatch, but see Lytze's answer at the dupe for a clever work-around.